# OSX + VB.Net, briefly what's required to port my program from windows, perhaps by mono?

Tags: vb.net, macos, mono, monodevelop

I have an order entry system which was developed using vb.net it uses an ms access database.

I think I might be able to use mono?

I'll need an IDE if possible.

Can someone tell me what I'll to download and what problems I might face, also any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [MoMA](http://www.mono-project.com/MoMA) to determine how well your application will run on Mono. It will analyze the app and tell you of any potential compatibility issues. As far as IDE goes, [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/) would work, but depending on the compatibility with Mono, you might be able to just continue to develop it on Windows. Since Mono is just an implementation of the CLR you may not have to make any code changes at all.

Mono supports ODBC for database connections, but you would have to install an ODBC driver (Such as [MDB Tools](http://mdbtools.sourceforge.net/)).

Comment: Oh what a shame, I haven't looked at mono for a few years. I ran the MoMA and there was lots of work to do on my project, although most of the DLLs were fine. Guess I'm going to have to run windows on my mac instead.

Answer (score 1):

> I think I might be able to use mono?

Porting applications can be tricky, generally it can go two ways:
- Get it running with minor tweaks.
- Stop trying and start developing from scratch.

MoMA helps, but you never know for sure until you try :)

Checkout MonoDevelop for Mac OSX:
http://monodevelop.com/